# MDX value instead of 0-1

Tags: mdx

```
CASE 
  WHEN 
        (
          [Date].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember
         ,[Measures].[Billing Reporting CFS - Total Amount EUR]
        )
      + 0
    = 0 
  THEN 
    CASE 
      WHEN 
          (
            ParallelPeriod
            (
              [Date].[Hierarchy].[Month]
             ,1
             ,[Date].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember
            )
           ,[Measures].[Billing Reporting CFS - Total Amount EUR]
          )
        > 0.01 
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END
  ELSE 0
END
```

The code is as follows, when in that month the total sales - actual sold then is 0 if total sales from last month differs from amount this month then is 1. However I want the 1 to change in the actual amount that is changed how would I go about this?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT

if value is above 0.01 then I want to see the actual value how do I do that?

Comment: what is the reason for the following inside your first condition `+ 0` ?

Comment: if the amounts would equal 0 for example 9-9 it would not show up in the results which is wanted. adding the 0 will make sure it shows up.

Comment: please also change `CASE` to `IIF` ... `CASE ` is always slower then `IIF`

Comment: ~What does this mean?... ` However I want the 1 to change in the actual amount that is changed how would I go about this?` Can you add in the rest of your script so we know the context of this code snippit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CASE 
  WHEN 
        (
          [Date].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember
         ,[Measures].[Billing Reporting CFS - Total Amount EUR]
        )
      + 0
    = 0 
  THEN 
    CASE 
      WHEN 
          (
            ParallelPeriod
            (
              [Date].[Hierarchy].[Month]
             ,1
             ,[Date].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember
            )
           ,[Measures].[Billing Reporting CFS - Total Amount EUR]
          )
        > 0.01 
      THEN ParallelPeriod([Date].[Hierarchy].[Month],1,[Date].Hierarchy].CurrentMember),[Measures].[Billing Reporting CFS - Total Amount EUR]
      ELSE 0
    END
  ELSE 0
END
```

Is the answer